# Issues with Ansible's default/error handling in a playbook

Tags: docker, ansible, provisioning

I'm having some issues with Ansible and the way it defaults to values. What I'm trying to accomplish is to bind a Docker container to on eth1, if it exists, otherwise use lo.

My initial approach was to use the [defaulting undefined variables](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#defaulting-undefined-variables) as follows:

```
shell: docker run -d -p {{ ansible_eth1.ipv4.address | default(127.0.0.1) }}:27017:27017 [...] dockerfile/mongodb
```

Unfortunately, Ansible threw the following error.

```
fatal: [server] => One or more undefined variables: 'ansible_eth1' is undefined
```

I also tried versions of this, such as:

```
shell: docker run -d -p {{ ansible_eth1.ipv4.address | ansible_lo.ipv4.address }}:27017:27017 [...] dockerfile/mongodb
```

That gave me another error:

```
failed: [server] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "docker run -d -p {# ansible_eth1.ipv4.address | ansible_lo.ipv4.address #}:27017:27017 [...]", "delta": "0:00:00.021053", "end": "2014-11-01     17:22:04.457375", "rc": 127, "start": "2014-11-01 17:22:04.436322"}
stderr: /bin/sh: 1: ansible_lo.ipv4.address: not found
2014/11/01 17:22:04 Invalid containerPort: {{
```

Next up, I tried using the `when` and ['is not defined'](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-and-includes) condition instead. It's less DRY, as I need two stanzas then.

```
- name: Start Mongo on loopback
  shell: docker run -d -p {{ ansible_lo.ipv4.address }}:27017:27017 [...] dockerfile/mongodb
  when: ansible_eth1.ipv4.address is not defined
```

That gave me the following error:

```
error while evaluating conditional: ansible_eth1.ipv4.address is not defined
```

Any Ansible experts out there that can point me in the right direction?

Oh, and I'm running ton Ansible 1.7.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with this:

```
ansible_eth1.ipv4.address | default(127.0.0.1)
```

Is that if `ansible_eth1` isn't a defined variable, then `ansible_eth1.ipv4.address` (or even `ansible_eth1.ipv4`) won't work. The solution is to apply the `default` filter to the variable that might not be there, which is `ansible_eth1`:

```
(ansible_eth1 | default(ansible_lo)).ipv4.address
```

Also note it's better practice to use `command` instead of `shell` unless you need some feature of the shell like pipe or redirection:

```
command: docker run -d -p {{ (ansible_eth1 | default(ansible_lo)).ipv4.address }}:27017:27017 [...] dockerfile/mongodb
```

Finally, note that Ansible has a [docker](http://docs.ansible.com/docker_module.html) module, so you may be able to use that directly here.

```
docker: "ports={{ (ansible_eth1 | default(ansible_lo)).ipv4.address }}:27017:27017 ..."
```

Comment: This may well answer the question, but we all love it when you explain why it does.

Comment: That did the trick and does make a lot of sense. Thanks!